# Readable is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

When I use:

```js
const { Readable } = require('stream');
```

Readable is undefined

When I use:

```js
import { Readable } from 'stream';
```

Readable is a empty object without properties

I see that node_packages contains stream-browserify, So I expect that is should be available in web browsers.

I use node 14.0.0 and angular 10.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the **`stream-browserify`** module your import should look like this:

```js
import { Readable } from 'stream-browserify';
```

Creating a new **`Readable`** instance and logging this produces the following:

```js
console.log(new Readable());
```

```
Readable {_readableState: {…}, readable: true, _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0…}
```

Check this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ybrxge?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to see it working